# Does time.sleep stop subprocess in python?

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, signals, sleep

We have C++ binary which will watch for some directories, and if any new file is added to those directories, C++ binary parses the file, creates new file and place it in some other directory.

We need to test the processed file. We used python to test this. Our python test case does below

- Start the C++ binary in sub process.
- Add some files in to a directory.
- Wait for some time to give some processing time to C++ binary.
- test the processed file content.

Below is the pseudo code I used.

```
file = 'SomeFile.txt'
prc = subprocess.Popen([cpppath, "-v", "-c", cfg], stdout=file)
# Add some files in to a directory
time.sleep(5) # To give time to C++ binary
# Test the content
```

But the issue I observed is, time.sleep() also stops C++ binary. I came to know this because we have a cron thread in C++ binary which will print **I am Alive** every second. This is getting printed till the time we call **timer.sleep()** in python. Once the sleep ends, Python test started testing the content. But as C++ binary didn't get chance to process the file in watch directory, test is failing.

My manager suggested to use signals. Python test case will create the files in watch directory and waits for sigusr1 and once the signal comes, test will proceed. C++ binary process the input files, place the processed file in a directory and signals parent process which is python test. But even for this, python test needs to use sleep() or pause() which will be the same issue again.

Can anyone please let me know if there is any way to solve the issue.

Comment: it should not block the c++ binary... if it is (It really shouldnt) use multiprocessing instead

Comment: One process should not be affected by another process sleeping. Multi-process systems would be pretty much unworkable if they were that intertwined.

Comment: Side note: If you can replace that sleep with some sort of message-passing, and this may be where your manager was going with signaling, so you don't waste time sleeping or run the risk of under-sleeping of the C++ code takes longer than anticipated.

Comment: Maybe the way how the "I am Alive" output is shown is affected by the `sleep`.

Comment: This is worth isolating and exploring. See if you can reproduce this behaviour in a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, calling `time.sleep()` in Python does not affect the binary started with subprocess.Popen(). There must be some other reason the test doesn't work as expected.